# Showing Newton’s Binomial Series by Verifying $(1 +x)y′=py$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that Newton’s Binomial series for any exponent $p$ will be equal
>   to the corresponding function by verifying the differential
>   equation:$$(1 +x)y′=py$$You will likely need the generalized “Pascal
>   triangle rule”
>
> $${p \choose k}={p−1 \choose k−1}+{p−1 \choose k}$$

I have that Newton's Binomial series says that

$$(1+x)^p=1+px+\frac{p(p−1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{p(p−1)(p−2)}{3!}x^3+···$$

I have also that

$$\begin{align*}
(1 +x)y′=py
&\iff\frac{1}{py}\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\frac{1}{1+x}\\\\
&\iff\int\frac{1}{py}dy=\int\frac{1}{1+x}dx\\\\
&\iff\frac{1}{p}ln(y)+c_1=ln(1+x)+c_2\\\\
&\iff ln(y)=p\cdot ln(1+x)+pc_3\\\\
&\iff ln(y)=ln\left(e^{pc_3}(x+1)^p\right)\\\\
&\iff y=e^{pc_3}(x+1)^p\\\\
&\iff y=c_4 (x+1)^p
\end{align*}$$

which equals $(1+x)^p$ if $c_4=1$ but I don't think this is what I am supposed to show, since I did not make use of the given Pascal triangle rule hint.

I think I need to use the given differential equation to show

$$1+px+\frac{p(p−1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{p(p−1)(p−2)}{3!}x^3+···$$

but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Differentiating the RHS of

$$(1+x)^p=1+px+\frac{p(p−1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{p(p−1)(p−2)}{3!}x^3+···$$

I get

$$p+2\frac{p(p-1)}{2!}x+3\frac{p(p-1)(p-2)}{3!}x^2+...$$
$$= p+2{p \choose 2}x+3{p \choose 3}x^2+...\\\\$$
$$= p+2\left({p-1 \choose 2-1}+{p-1 \choose 2}\right)x+3\left({p-1 \choose 3-1}+{p-1 \choose 3}\right)x^2+...$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

You did half. Now you  are supposed to show that the series satisfies the same differential equation, which you can do  by differentiating term by term and applying Pascal's triangle...